# React set variable value from a call back from child component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

I am learning React and need some help in finding out a problem with this code and understanding what am I not doing incorrectly. Parent component is MyMap and it needs values for Lat from its child component which is Search bar.
Call back function name is setLatInfo and it will set the value for the lat variable defined in useState.

The error that I am seeing is Assignments to the 'setLatInfo' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect.

on the function setLatInfo = (latInfo: number)

How can I assign a call back function within an useEffect block?

```
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";

const MyMap: FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [lat, setLat] = useState();
  let setLatInfo: (latInfo: number) => void;

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = () => {
      
      // map?.map
     // (map as any)?.map.addLayer(h3Layer);
    };
  
    setLatInfo = (latInfo: number) => {   // this entire function is showing error 
      setLat(latInfo);
      console.log(lat);
      console.log(latInfo);
    };

  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar
        parentCallbackLat={setLatInfo}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Probably better to define `setLatInfo` inside the main function body using `useCallback`. Then you can call it inside the `useEffect` *and* pass it as a prop to the `<SearchBar`/>

Comment: Thanks Jayce444, I have not useCallback before, do you mind showing it with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to check out the `usCallback` syntax and how it works, as well as some examples so you can understand exactly what's happening with it. A basic example for your use case would be:

```
const [lat, setLat] = useState();

const setLatInfo = useCallback(latInfo => {
    console.log(latInfo);
    setLat(latInfo);
},[setLat]);

useEffect(() => {
    setLatInfo("initial value");
}, [setLatInfo]);

return <SearchBar parentCallbackLat={setLatInfo} />;
```

Also, just so you know React state changes are async and you can't print their new values on the next line

Comment: Trying it @Jaycee444 and let you know.

Comment: Oh that is good to know that I cant print the new values. How else can I check them?

Comment: So why are we  using this line of code?setLatInfo("initial value");  Why do we need to assign a value to it?  Its a function, why does it need an initial value?

Comment: I believe if you just print the state value in the main body of the component that will work, since that's run every time the component re-renders. You could also put it into a useEffect, like so `useEffect(() => console.log(lat), [lat]);`. You don't *need* to give it an initial value, I just did that because the useEffect will run on the initial render of the component, so it will be called then. I just gave it that value to indicate that.

Comment: thank you so much. I think this helped a lot. I am reading on useCallback hook now. One thing I am not able to understand is why see why it didnt work without the useCallback..